# Flutter fromJson with integer / num having problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use `fromJson` method and I am having problem with integer values. I tried to use num as well but no luck. Even with `String` has no luck. The data I am trying to parse is this:

`flutter: [{id: e3fedf5e, name: Customer 1, gender: 0, phone: 09623562, payable: 0, receivable: 54273356, collectionSize: 2}]`

Please advise.

[Code overview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Lvi.png)

Comment: just call the endpoint again in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to know the exact datatype in the returned json, or just use my answer below

Comment: Thank you. I've marked your answer as accepted. It's all good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```dart
receivable: "${json['receivable'] ?? 0}"; // this make whatever coming a string
receivable: int.parse("${json['receivable'] ?? '0'}"); // this make whatever coming a parsed integer
receivable: double.parse("${json['receivable'] ?? '0.0'}"); // this make whatever coming a double
```

the work around here is
- converting the returned json to string
- then parsing it to int or double
- with making sure if it's null put zero